# Migrating Cases between Orgs - preserve/set CaseNumber

Tags: soql, case, auto-number

As a system field I am unable to set `CaseNumber` on the default Case object when I do my imports from my legacy Org. I've already created a custom Permissions Set [as per](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Enabling-Create-Audit-Fields-for-Professional-Edition) and In there I do see Edit Access column for Case Object but the checkbox is grayed out for Case Number. 
Is there a way to allow setting that field, I would only need it allowed during an initial import to preserve the original case numbers as they're often quoted in emails and comments by my colleauges; which I've also migrated.

This is in Enterprise Edition.

Comment: As case numbers are created incrementally, are you not able to sort a .csv by case number, insert dummy records where cases are missing, save, and then insert? This would only work on a fresh org where you've not already started creating cases and the count is starting at 1. Just an idea and not an answer as I've not tested.

Comment: It would in theory but we've had the old ORG for years and execs only want the last few months migrated. Might have to be the additional field. At least wit hthe audit field edits enabled I get to preserve the timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Case.CaseNumber doesn't fall under [Audit fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm). So unfortunately you cannot unlock them.

Option would be to create a new field for holding old Case numbers.